# Почему возникает ошибка в Postgre

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Я только начинающий в сфере изучения БД и есть недопонимание ошибки на скрине ниже.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: У вас в запросе 2 разных алиаса (а и s), но используется только 1 таблица, да и той не присвоен алиас

Comment: Плюс ко всему у вас группировка не валидна - нужно группировать по всем выводимым полям, ясно не считая count

Answer (score 0):

В вашем SQL в блоке SELECT при обращении используются альясы "s","a".
В блоке from данные альясы не объявлены.
Скорее всего колонка "model" находится в другой таблице.